# Only one Horizontal line below the Caption of Algorithm in latex

Tags: captions, rules, algorithm2e

I want only one Horizontal line below the caption in latex algorithm but in my case it gives line below and above the caption as shown. How can I get the desired output ?[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \label{algo:datapacket}
  \caption{Algorithm for selecting the forwarder among PFNs.}
  % do something
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
 \begin{algorithm}[H]
\label{algo:datapacket}
\caption{Algorithm for selecting the forwarder among PFNs.}  
% do something
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}`

Comment: Please add the code to your post, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro that does the rule above the caption is `\@algocf@pre@ruled`. You can redefine it to do nothing:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\def\@algocf@pre@ruled{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Algorithm for selecting the forwarder among PFNs.}
  \label{algo:datapacket}
  \While{Meaning of Life = 42}{
    Hello world!
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Also, the `\label` has to be after the `\caption`.